# Memory Error when parsing two large data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes each around 400k rows call them a and b. What I want to do is for every row in df b find the account number in that row in data frame a. If it exists, i want to drop that row from dataframe a. Problem is, when I try to run this code, i keep getting memory errors. Initially I was using iterrows, but that seems to be bad when working with large datasets, so i switched to apply, but I'm running into the same error. Below is simplified pseudocode of what I'm trying:

```
def reduceAccount(accountID):
    idx = frameA.loc[frameA["AccountID"] == accountID].index
    frameB.drop(idx, inplace=True)

frameB["AccountID"].apply(reduceAccount)
```

I've even tried some shennanigans like iterating thru the first few hundred/thousand rows, but after a cycle, i still hit the memory error, which makes me think im still loading things into memory rather than clearing thru. Is there a better way to reduce dataframeA than what im trying? Note that I do not want to merge the frames (yet) just remove any row in dataframe a that has a duplicate key in dataframe b.

Comment: You say you want to drop rows from dataframe a, but your code drops rows from frameB. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, the drop should be frameA drop after matching its index off of frame bs account ID. Just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in order to see all values to filter, you will need to store both DFs in memory at some point. You can improve your efficiency somewhat by not using `apply()`, which is still an iterator. The following code is a more efficient, vectorized approach using boolean masking directly.

```
dfB[~dfB["AccountID"].isin(dfA["AccountID"])]
```

However, if storage is the problem, then this may still not work. Some approaches to consider are chunking the data, as you say you've already tried, or some of the options in the documentation on [enhancing performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html)

Comment: This worked perfectly to give me a diff dataframe that i could merge into my frameB! Thanks for this. Not doing a rowwise operation seems to have worked to get past my memory exeeded error. At least, I assume that isin isn't a row by row iteration and thats why it seemed to work. Upshot is that this proved exactly what I need.

Comment: Boolean masking and similar operations are optimized in numpy to perform at the C level, so you avoid any looping at all, and almost always get significant performance improvements. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want every row in A which 'AccountID' is not in B.

This can be done with a left join: `frameA = frameA.join(frameB, on='AccountID', how='left')`

I think this is best in terms of **memory efficiency** for you'll be leveraging the power of pandas built-in optimized code.

Comment: I thought about this solution on my way to lunch and it does seem far and away the right answer for this. I'm hoping this iteration with action taken issue won't crop up again though, because I still don't know how to resolve memory errors with apply...however I think your solution will work. When I return I'll give it a shot and update here

Comment: Just wanted to chime back in here with the results of trying this. Rather than getting a difference between the two, it seems that (since frame b always has at LEAST all the ids in framea) that frame a had the same number of rows before and after the Join. This didn't seem to get me where I needed to be, but the isin comment below did.

Comment: Good, but you stated that you're trying to reduce dataframe **A**. If A is always completely contained in B, than A should always reduce to an empty set and your question wouldn't make sense. i nthis case you want to reduce B, not A.